# TableView Cell Auto Height

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a TextView in the `UITableViewCell`, and I want my height TableViewCell is auto according TextView height.

I had worked some code, but it display on the IOS 8 only, I want it can action on the IOS 7.

Please help me!

Thanks all.

Here is image my code, it work on the IOS 8 very good.

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    NSString *messageText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [DicMessagesData objectForKey:@"ContentMessage"]];

    CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(CELL_CONTENT_WIDTH - (CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN * 2), 20000.0f);

    NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
    paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;

    CGRect textRect = [messageText boundingRectWithSize:constraint options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:@{NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyle.copy} context:nil];

    return textRect.size.height + 30;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this code:

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

  NSString *text = @"your text";
  CGSize maximumLabelSize = CGSizeMake(CELL_CONTENT_WIDTH, 9999);

  UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] init];
  textField.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:18];
  textField.text = text;
  CGSize expectSize = [textField sizeThatFits:maximumTXTSize];
  return expectSize.height + 40;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the best method i have found :

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

  NSString *text = @"your text";
  CGSize maximumLabelSize = CGSizeMake(CELL_CONTENT_WIDTH, 9999);

  UILabel *notesLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
  notesLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:18];
  notesLabel.text = text;  
  notesLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
  notesLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
  CGSize expectSize = [notesLabel sizeThatFits:maximumLabelSize];
  return expectSize.height + 40;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A few months ago I faced the same problem. Thankfully I found a simple blog on [Table View Cells With Varying Row Heights](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2014/02/14/table-view-cells-with-varying-row-heights.html). It will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It works. This will give dynamic height for each tableview cell based on the content.

```
- (CGFloat)heightForText:(NSString *)bodyText
{
    NSAttributedString *attrStr = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:bodyText];
    CGFloat width = 278;
    CGRect rect = [attrStr boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(width, MAXFLOAT) options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin | NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading context:nil];
    return rect.size.height+10;
```

}

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    lblComment.numberOfLines = 0;
    lblComment.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    CGFloat rowHeight = [self heightForText:[[allCommentsArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"comment"]];
    lblComment.frame = CGRectMake(25, 25, 278, rowHeight);
    NSLog(@"rowHeight=%f", rowHeight);
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
        CGFloat rowHgt=[self heightForText:[[allCommentsArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"comment"]];
        NSLog(@"rowHgt=%f", rowHgt);
        return rowHgt+25;
}
```

[image]